# VB script to work for loading objects from local directory with specified names on Range B

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to write a code for macro, that will load files from my local directory into excel sheet of Column say ("C"), the names on files should match names on Column ("B"). If any of the files doesn't find for the names given in column B it should skip that row of loading files and continues to next column. I'am difficulty in writing as I am new to VB. I tried somehow but, my script working to load files from directory and loading names. Please help!! thank you all,

Code:

```
Sub Insert_OLE_Object()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ActiveSheet = example1

    Folderpath = "C:\Documents and Settings\my\Desktop\folder1"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files

    For Each fls In listfiles
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Range("B" & Counter).Value = fls.Name
        strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Example1").OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=strCompFilePath, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:=strCompFilePath, Left:=20, Top:=40, Width:=150, Height:=10).Select
            Sheets("example1").Activate
            Sheets("example1").Range("C" & ((Counter - 1) * 3) + 1).Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: what is in your column B? full name with path ("C:\...\folder1\test.txt") or just file name ("test.txt")? if file name is it with extension ("test.txt") of not ("test")?

Comment: Column B has file names ("not folder path") of objects that to load on column C.

Comment: is it with extension ("test.txt") of not ("test")?

Comment: no not .txt it is just with ("test")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Insert_OLE_Object()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim strCompFilePath As String, Folderpath As String, fullpath As String
    Dim obj As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'change to suit
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Example1")

    'change B1:B5 to suit
    Set rng = ws.Range("B1:B5")
    Folderpath = "C:\Documents and Settings\my\Desktop\folder1"

    For Each c In rng
        strCompFilePath = Dir(Folderpath & "\" & Trim(c.Value) & ".*")
        'if file with this name found, embed it
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            fullpath = Folderpath & "\" & strCompFilePath
            Set obj = ws.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=fullpath, Link:=False, _
                                        DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconIndex:=1, _
                                        IconLabel:=fullpath)
            With obj
                .Left = c.Offset(, 1).Left
                .Top = c.Offset(, 1).Top
                .Width = c.Offset(, 1).ColumnWidth
                .Height = c.Offset(, 1).RowHeight
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much; it worked also I tried of specifying folder path as directory of Range function instead of specifying folder path in code:

  Folderpath = Range("D1").Value

as D1 carries "C:\Documents and Settings\my\Desktop\folder1" and it worked.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I tried changing different columns to work on it but unfortunately files are loading in the column 'C'only.

Comment: For example: For Each H In myRange (here specifying for H)

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand what you mean, but in line `For Each c In rng` variable `c` doesn't mean "write in column C", it's just variable name (you can change it to, say, `For Each singleCell In rng`). If you want to embed files in col H, use `c.Offset(, 6).` (assuming that `rng` refers to column B) or more explicit `ws.Range("H" & c.Row).` instead `c.Offset(, 1)`

Comment: Yes it worked by specifying : ws.Range("H" & c.Row). Thanks again!